# I have a batch file that echos multiple lines. I would like to output it into the file but the file only shows 1 line

Tags: command-line, batch, echo

This is what I have:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@echo off
set num=0
set "suffix="
for /f "delims=" %%s in ('dir /b /a-d /o:gen') do (
   if /i "%%~xs" equ "!suffix!" (
      set /a num+=1
   ) else (
      if !num! neq 0 echo "!suffix!"     !num!
      set num=1
      set suffix=%%~xs
   )
)

(
echo "%suffix%"    %num% 
) >>"%~dp0%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2% Logfile.txt"
```

I have searched through the forum and internet with no results. Mind if someone point me in the right direction?

Edit: Found the error, below attached for reference.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@echo off
set num=0
set "suffix="
for /f "delims=" %%s in ('dir /b /a-d /o:gen') do (
   if /i "%%~xs" equ "!suffix!" (
      set /a num+=1
   ) else (
      if !num! neq 0 echo "!suffix!"     !num! >>"%~dp0%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2% Logfile.txt"
      set num=1
      set suffix=%%~xs
   )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "echo" stands outside of `for / do` - loop that is why it will be printed only once.
Put it **INTO** the `do` section like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%s in ('dir /b /a-d /o:gen') do (
   if /i "%%~xs" equ "!suffix!" (
      set /a num+=1
   ) else (
      if !num! neq 0 echo "!suffix!"     !num!
      set num=1
      set suffix=%%~xs
   )

   echo "%suffix%"    %num% >>"%~dp0%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2% Logfile.txt"
)
```

Comment: I have briefly tested this, which seems to be not working at the moment. However I think this is the correct direction.Edit:currently re-editing and testing.

Comment: Yes, I was not paying enough attention to the code, only assuming that the answer is listed at the end of the code. Thanks!